# Is it possible to get request information from a rxjs-timeout-error?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to improve our current implementation of error handling and one part of it is the better description of errors in general and also in testing environments. I do this for an Ionic app but since my problem lies within the rxjs timeout-method, I think this is neglectable.

One part im currently stuck on is the correct visualization (error message) of timeout errors since they don't seem to contain anything of value at all. I'd like to show to the user which request was the origin of the timeout error when the error happens and the user sees. In the case of testing environments additional thinks like url, device-version, etc. should be shown as well.

But all the Timeout-Error contains seems to be a stacktrace of the javascript library beneath handling the post request.

So, my question is if there is a way to add or retrieve additional information from an rxjs timeout error?

Below you can see how the TimeoutError from rxjs looks for me.
[image: screenshot of the error in console]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeoutError` has nothing to do with values emitted by the source Observable. Still, it's thrown when there are no emissions from the source so what how could it contain any information anyway.

What you can do however is use `catchError` to get the error that produced, turn it into another error and send it further with `throwError`:

```
...
catchError(e => throwError({...e, ...whatever}))
```

You can for example check whether the error is an instance of `TimeoutError` and if it is the do something with it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the idea, didn't think of that. Im now intercepting the error right at the start and add my request information to the error!